Qiskit runtime backen cannot state_preperation
I am trying to run a circuit on hardware, for that I need to initialise the state.
initial_state = StatePreparation([1/np.sqrt(2),0,1/np.sqrt(2),0,0,0,0,0])
qc = QuantumCircuit(initial_state.num_qubits)
qc.append(initial_state, qc.qubits)

But running this on hardware
service = QiskitRuntimeService(channel='ibm_quantum', token='YOURENOTGETTINGMYTOKEN')


backend = service.least_busy(operational=True, simulator=False)
pm = generate_preset_pass_manager(target=backend.target, optimization_level=1)

with Session(service=service, backend=backend) as session:
    # Submit a request to the Estimator primitive within the session.
    estimator = EstimatorV2(mode=session)
    estimator.options.resilience_level = 1  # Set options.
    job = estimator.run(
        [(qc, observable_operators)]
    )

I get an error that state_preparation is not supported by the backend?

IBMInputValueError: 'The instruction state_preparation on qubits (0, 1, 2) is not supported by the target system. Circuits that do not match the target hardware definition are no longer supported after March 4, 2024. See the transpilation documentation (https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/transpile) for instructions to transform circuits and the primitive examples (https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/run/primitives-examples) to see this coupled with operator transformations.

I assume state preparation is supported as is seems quite essential. Moreover it seems that my approach is suggested in another question Qiskit Runtime forbids reset gate?
The documentation links mentioned in the error aren't really helpful

It seems you defined a pass manager object, but never used it to transpiler your circuit. If you don’t transpile, the backend will not be able to recognize instructions that are not part of its basis set.

That seems to be the case. I thought I followed an example. Guess I can't read very well.

@diemilio Can you add an answer to the question so that the OP can accept it?
